# Jquery tab navigation not working properly

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 
   <body> 
    <div data-role="tabs"> 

        <div data-role="navbar"> 
          <ul> 
           <li><a href="#tabone" >one</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#tabtwo">two</a></li> 
          </ul> 
         </div> 
         
         <div id="tabone" class="ui-content"> 
         <h1>First tab contents</h1>
          <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none"><button class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-left">Go back to page 1</button>
          </a>
         </div> 
         
         <div id="tabtwo" class="ui-content"> 
          <h1>Second tab contents</h1> 
         </div> 
         
    </div> 
     
</body>
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong with it, I've tried a couple different ways of arranging it but it just comes out like the image below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I do not see where you have loaded the jQuery or the jQuery UI Library. These must be loaded to a Script must be added to initialize the Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example based on the Demo: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

```js
$(function() {
  $("div[data-role='tabs']").tabs();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div data-role="tabs">
  <ul data-role="navbar">
    <li><a href="#tabone">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabtwo">two</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabone" class="ui-content">
    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
    <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none"><button class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-left">Go back to page 1</button></a>
  </div>
  <div id="tabtwo" class="ui-content">
    <h1>Second tab contents</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```